# Create a RPM repo and hosted in a cloud service?

Tags: fedora, rpm

I want to know how can I create my own Fedora repository and if the packages can be hosted in a Cloud service like Dropbox or Google Drive?.

Comment: There are many articles out there for hosting a yum repo on S3.

Answer (score 2):

If your software is open source and doesn't have any [legal encumbrances](https://docs.pagure.org/copr.copr/user_documentation.html#what-i-can-build-in-copr) (e.g. patents) then you can build and host it using [Fedora's COPR service](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/), which provides build service and hosting for open source packages for Fedora and CentOS/RHEL.

This service is similar in concept to Ubuntu's PPA archives, but obviously [works differently](https://docs.pagure.org/copr.copr/user_documentation.html).